# Find time difference between two pulses using PIC16F628

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to find time difference between two pulses using PIC16F628.
I am using a 4MHz external oscillator, MikroC compiler.

As a simple example let's assume there is a push button. When we press it, it sends a high signal to a pin. We press this button twice with some delay in between, I want to find the time difference between these two button presses.

Thank you.

Comment: What programming language are you using for your code? Also, FWIW, you may or may not find more help for a uC specific question like this over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I am using C language, hence MikroC compiler. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK. The simplest solution is to use a timer and a counter: start the timer with counter at 0 on the first pulse, and store the counter value on the second pulse. I'm looking for PIC specifics to give you an example ATM.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the simplest way to do this is to use a timer/counter combo. I found this quick tutorial on how to do this specifically for PIC: http://www.mikroe.com/chapters/view/17/chapter-4-examples/#c4v5.

Have a look at 4.5 and 4.6, they give you exactly the information you'll need to get the count of timer intervals between pulses. The basic technique is to start a timer, associate an interrupt handler (Read: function) with the timer, and then increment a counter everytime the interrupt handler is called. Next time you see the pulse, read what the counter value is.

After that, all you need to know is the timebase you've set the counter to (which will be some integer subdivision of your oscillator rate, and is selectable in code usually) and you can convert # of timer intervals to time in seconds/millis/nanos.

Comment: Hey, that was fast, thanks a lot. I'll get back to you later once I try this.